# particles.js animation area is blocked by text and images

Tags: css

I would like to get particles animation in the background of the entire green area but text and images are blocking (see http://billiving-qa.azurewebsites.net). The animation appears only at the bottom of the green area.

This is the wrapping div:

```
<div class="jumbotron" id="particles-js">
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your canvas element is being pushed down by the container. To avoid that, either place it inside the container or use absolute positioning like:

```
canvas {position: absolute; top: 0}
```

Comment: Moving this to an inner div didn't work:
  <div class="jumbotron" >
        <div id="particles-js">

Comment: Also, adding the class you've suggested doesn't work either

Comment: Tried wrapping it under the container, doesn't work as well:   <div class="jumbotron" >

        <div class="container">

            <div id="particles-js">

Comment: I didn't add a class, just 2 rules to the canvas element. I can send you a screenshot of it working if you wish. Just add those two rules, and nothing else

Comment: This works, but now unable to click the signup button: http://billiving-qa.azurewebsites.net. Any idea how to get around it?

Comment: Sure, you can add `pointer-events: none;` to the canvas element, but then it won't respond to mouse movement. You should probably check their docs to see how they suggest setting up multiple layers like that.

Comment: Fixed by adding z-index:-1 and opacity:0.99.
You can see it here: http://www.billiving.com

Many thanks!!